# Web API2 NinjectWebCommon.cs do not appear

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, nuget, ninject

I am doing an `Empty Web API in Visual Studio 2013` Framework 4.5. Obviously `NinjectWebCommon.cs` do not appear.

I installed via Nuget,

- Ninject,
- Ninject.Web.Common,
- Ninject.MVC5,
- Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost,
- Ninject.Web.WebApi,
- Ninject.web.WebApi.WebHost

  but `NinjectWebCommon.cs` still does not appear.

What else do I need to install?

Can I add that file manually?

thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It looks like the most recent Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost 3.3.0 NuGet package no longer includes the NinjectWebCommon.cs. Older versions, such as 3.2.0 do include this file.

Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost 3.3.0 provides a NinjectHttpApplication class you can derive from and use instead of the NinjectWebCommon.cs. The [wiki documentation for Ninject](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application) does not seem to have been updated but it looks like using the NinjectHttpApplication is one documented approach, as shown below:

```
public class MvcApplication : NinjectHttpApplication
{
   public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
   {
       filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
   }

   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
   {
       routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

       routes.MapRoute(
           "Default", // Route name
           "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
           new
           {
               controller = "Home",
               action = "Index",
               id = UrlParameter.Optional
           });
   }

   protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
   {
       var kernel = new StandardKernel();
       RegisterServices(kernel);
       return kernel;
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Load your modules or register your services here!
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
   private void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
   {
       // e.g. kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
   }

   protected override void OnApplicationStarted()
   {
       base.OnApplicationStarted();

       AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
       RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
       RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
   }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to *resolve* a dependency.

Comment: @Alisson you can simply add your dependency into the RegisterServices function. ie kernel.Bind<IMyClass>().To<MyClass>();

Comment: For injection in web api controller as well, add this line to CreateKernel method:
System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Ninject.WebApi.DependencyResolver.NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);

Answer (score 10):

Tested with latest Ninject: 
Create an Empty Web Application and select the checkboxes for Mvc and Web Api

Install Nuget Package: Ninject.Web.WebApi.WebHost

Install Nuget Package: WebActivatorEx

Create a class in App_Start named NinjectWebCommon.cs

```
 [assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
 [assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

 namespace <YOURNAMESPACE>
 {
     public static class NinjectWebCommon
     {
         private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

         public static void Start()
         {
             DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
             DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
             bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
         }

         public static void Stop()
         {
             bootstrapper.ShutDown();
         }

         private static IKernel CreateKernel()
         {
             var kernel = new StandardKernel();
             kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
             kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

             RegisterServices(kernel);
             return kernel;
         }
         private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
         {
           //kernel.Bind<IRepo>().ToMethod(ctx => new Repo("Ninject Rocks!"));
         }
     }
 }
```

Configure your DI in RegisterServices

Add dependency to Mvc or Web Api Controllers constructor parameters

Hope it helps, thanks.

Comment: This worked like a charm for me. I'm still unclear as to why they went away from including this automatically. I saw above the way to inherit NinjectHttpApplication in MVC, but from what I can see WebApi behaves a bit differently. I'll investigate more later when I have the time. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

If you want get auto-generated `NinjectWebCommon` class in *App_Start* folder, you should change value of `Dependency behavior` option on `Highest` in ***NuGet Package Manager***.
It'll download all dependencies including NinjectWebCommon. 
[image]

Comment: the answer didn't work for me with Ninject.MVC5.3.3.0...
VS 2017

Comment: Won't work for me with Ninject.MVC5.3.3.0 VS2019 16.2
But i've just see the file create into the folder but not included into the project. Someone else the same issue?

Comment: the answer didn't work for me with Ninject.Web.WebAPI.3.3.1... VS 2019 v16.4.2