# Updating to latest stable version in Ninject removes NinjectWebCommon.cs (Web API v2)

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, ninject

I think I may be losing my mind, I've updated all `Ninject` packages to the latest stable version which then removes `NinjectWebCommon.cs`

"We" have a fair few Live Web API projects running with an earlier version and all is working great! But having said that, when I try to remove and revert to an old version, we're hit with many assembly issues.

Really, I suppose the question is after an hour's worth of "googling", is there a `nuget` package that I'm missing with the `Ninject` updates?

**To reiterate when updating all `Ninject` packages it removes the `NinjectWebCommon.cs`**

**Current Packages:**

```
  <package id="Ninject" version="3.3.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Ninject.MVC5" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.Common" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.WebApi" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.WebApi.WebHost" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="WebActivatorEx" version="2.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="WebApiContrib.IoC.Ninject" version="0.9.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
```

Hopefully I'm not missing the obvious and it's generally a problem/bug.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: apparently `NinjectWebCommon` is not shipped with the latest version but is still needed. I would suggest trying: clean checkout. Update packages. Revert deletion of NinjectWebCommon.cs + add it back to project.

Comment: @BatteryBackupUnit May be worth wrapping that up as an answer? So I can close off the question. Certainly answered it for me.

Comment: great, sure, created an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `NinjectWebCommon.cs` is not shipped with with 3.3.0 but is still required.
When updating, I recommend to:

- clean checkout
- update packages
- revert deletion of NinjectWebCommon.cs
- add NinjectWebCommon.cs pack to the project

Alternatively write your own implementation like documented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47002329/684096).

Comment: Thanks for your time.